# Is there an observable operator that is similar to forkJoin but only errors out if all of the request fails?

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular5

For example

```
    return Observable.forkJoin([
            getData1(),
            getData2(),
            getData3(),
            getData4()
        ])
```

If one of them fails, the subscriber that subscribes to the forkJoin observable fails, is there an operator that only fails if all of them fails?

Comment: What do you expect the returned observable to look like if one of the inner ones errored? In other words, what should the i-th value in the array be if the i-th observable errored?

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the design of rxjs that ANY error causes the chain of observables to fail.

It sounds like the condition you are trying to trap is not really a failure, but a normal case - if you change the sub-observables to detect the error and then return a value which can be detected down stream with something like a map or a filter, then you will be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: so I am fine if it go to the `catch` statement of the subscriber, but I loose out on all the information that other call returns, I could just do 4 calls without `forkjoin`, but I was wondering if there is an easier way

Comment: What is the error - is the http request failing? or is it a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in getting error from inner observables, `materialize` might be way to go:

```
const pluckError = (obs: Observable<any>) =>
  obs.materialize().filter(x => x.kind === 'E')

Observable.forkJoin(
  obs1.pipe(pluckError),
  obs2.pipe(pluckError)
 ....
)
```

It is important to note outer observable shouldn't raise error as it'll terminate whole observable, but you can catch / or get Notification metadata using materialize and only pick up error to make forkjoin completes.